# Google DirectoryAPI adding wrong email

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

Google's Directory API incorrectly adding the personal gmail address to a google group when I use the api to insert a non-gmail address. This only happens for a subset of addresses for several domains @indiana.edu, @arizona.edu... (I assume it is connected to the organizations own use of GoogleApps).

I can reproduce the issue using the [Google-Api-Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/admin/directory_v1/), without any code, but I noticed the issue using google-api-php-client.

```
$gData = $this->service->members->insert($groupEmail,$gMember);
```

I have filed a ticket with Google. Has anyone encountered this issue, or can you shed light into how a personal gmail account is linked to an @organizatio.edu account in GoogleApps.

Answer (score 0):

Google Confirmed this was a bug in the GoogleAPI.  It was fixed in September 2013.